# ASP.NET MVC App takes ages to respond sometimes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET MVC app running in IIS7.  Sometimes when I type the URL into a browser it takes 5-10 seconds before it responds, then after that it is fine.  It's like it's taking it's time starting/waking up.

How should I best proceed with trying to identify the problem?

Comment: Maybe IIS recycles your application after a period of user inactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably normal behaviour rather than a problem. It's probably going to sleep because it hasn't had any requests for a long time. You can try changing the Idle Timeout under the Application Pool's advanced settings or if you're running .NET 4.0, you can keep the application [always running](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening right after you've edited ASPX files or rebuilt other .NET sources (e.g., *.cs), then it's probably because of the JIT native code generation of the .NET code.  This can be solved by a warm-up utility like the (currently defunct, sadly) [IIS warm-up module](http://forums.iis.net/t/1176740.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASP.NET Mini Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) to check what takes too long to load. Web.config re-saving can cause your application to be restarted and if your website is not compiled, it takes longer to load as well, plus if you have a heavy database call. In other words, there's no general solution for this, it depends on how you design the application and then improve what appear to be not efficient.